# Combining multiple services in a single Azure web role

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-web-roles

I have a web application hosted on Azure, which spins up roles for a short period of time to perform a task. This task is necessary, so I can't do without it. I want to combine these services and assign them to a single role, so that when the service is run ten times in an hour, I don't get billed for ten hours of use.

I found a blog post and [potential solution](https://github.com/dfberry/AzureMultiThreadedWorkerRole), created in 2012. However, this project is horribly out of date, uses MVC3, and uses packages that haven't been available for several years now. Trying to make it work is not feasible.

Is multiple services on a single role still a valid solution, or do I have to take another approach?

Comment: Web / worker role stuff hasn't changed in years: It's still just a Windows Server VM that starts off fresh with every deployment (or OS update). If you can get your services installed from your startup script, then you're good to go. Breaking into separate roles is a function of scale. I'm fairly certain this has been asked before on StackOverflow (just can't find it right now). *Note: I'm not addressing the use of web/worker roles vs some other Azure service - that's a rather broad topic and out of scope for here.*

Comment: @DavidMakogon I'm aware that it's possible, but not sure how to do it. The example that I found was complete, but not incredibly explanatory, so trying to do the same with modern frameworks is difficult inasmuch as finding the right libraries and suchlike. I've also never really done this before, so I'm having some trouble getting started.

Answer (score 1):

> I found a blog post and potential solution, created in 2012. However, this project is horribly out of date, uses MVC3, and uses packages that haven't been available for several years now. Trying to make it work is not feasible.
>
> Is multiple services on a single role still a valid solution, or do I have to take another approach?

I agree with David Makogon, Web / worker role stuff hasn't changed in years. If you’d like to include background processing into your web role, you could still create the web role and **override** the **Run()** method in class WebRole and implement worker tasks with your logic in Run() method. The following simple sample that add message to storage queue works fine on my side, please refer to it.

```
public class WebRole : RoleEntryPoint
{

    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        return base.OnStart();
    }

    public override void Run()
    {
        //Replace the code with your logic

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("my connection string");
        CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();        
        CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("mymessage");
    
        while (true)
        {
            CloudQueueMessage message = new CloudQueueMessage("worker run at " + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString());

            queue.AddMessage(message);
    
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000);

        }
    }
}
```